# Filename gets printed but files are not deleted afterwards

Tags: powershell

I stumbled upon a problem when scripting in PowerShell:

```
$root="c:\users"
$users=get-childitem -path $root -exclude administrator, public
foreach ($user in $users)
 {
 $folder= join-path -path $user -childpath "downloads\*"
 Get-childitem $folder -recurse | ? LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) | Out-File -FilePath .\files.txt -append | Remove-Item
 }

 Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

It's supposed to check every user's download directory and delete all files that are older than 2 days.

Files.txt looks perfect, but those files do not get deleted.
I tried several methods to delete them but none works.

And is there an easy way to summarize how many MB or GB I cleaned?
Just a little feature I'd add as long as it's not to much to do.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get deleted cause you are piping output of `Out-File` to `Remove-Item`.

The way piping works is the preceding command is being sent to next one.
More on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1

Since you want an extensive info about deleted items, script is much bigger than anticipated (we need to get info about every file and folder :)) and might look something like below (explanation in comments):

```
$root = "c:\users"
$users = Get-ChildItem -path $root -exclude administrator, public

#Initialization of reporting variables
$deletedFiles = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$globalSize = 0;

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $userDownloads = Join-Path -path $user.FullName -childpath "downloads"

    #Getting folders from downloads, which has been older than 2 days
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $userDownloads -recurse -Directory;
    #Getting files from downloads
    Get-ChildItem $userDownloads -File | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) | ForEach-Object {
        #Adding files from downloads folder that are older than 2 days
        $deletedFiles.Add($_.FullName)
    }

    #Handling folders existing in Downloads folder
    foreach ($folder in $folders) { 
        Write-Host "Handling folder $folder"
        #Getting files from folder (lastwritetime check should not be necessary)
        $files = Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
        #Add item to deleted files list
        $files | Foreach-Object { $deletedFiles.Add($_.FullName) }
    }

    #Handling all files
    foreach ($file in $deletedFiles) {
        #Getting item size in MBs
        $size = (Get-Item $file | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length) / 1MB;
        try {
            #Remving item by its full path
            Remove-Item $file #-WhatIf #to test script
            #Add item size to deleted items size summary
            $globalSize += [System.Math]::Round($size, 2)
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output "Could not delete file $file`: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }

    $folders | Foreach-Object {
        #Let's check if folders are empty
        if (!(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName)) {
            #folder is empty, we can delete it
            Remove-Item $_.FullName #-WhatIf #for testing
        }
    }
}

#Write summary
Write-Host "Deleted $($deletedFiles.Count) files with $globalSize MB in total"

#Write deleted items to file
$deletedFiles | Out-File C:\Temp\files.txt

# Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Whoah thanks! I'll try this out the next few days